# dart_frog: Parameter likes is not a list

Tags: postgresql, flutter, orm, dart-pub

I'm trying to fetch data from PostgresSQL deployed locally using Docker Image.

#### Package used

- [dart_frog](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_frog) -> Backend
- [stormberry](https://pub.dev/packages/stormberry) -> ORM

I've used `dart_frog` ask backend. Now, I inserted following data in postgres using Postico client:

[image]

As an ORM I'm using `stormberry`, for parsing dart classes methods to SQL queries and vice versa. Now, while hitting my end points `http:localhost:8080/api/v1/posts/` its showing me the following error:

```
ConverterException: Parameter likes is not a List
package:stormberry/src/internals/text_encoder.dart 137:7   TypedMap.getList
package:stormberry/src/internals/text_encoder.dart 147:12  TypedMap.getListOpt
package:db/src/models/post/post.schema.dart 143:18         PostQueryable.decode
package:stormberry/src/internals/view_query.dart 48:46     ViewQuery.apply.<fn>
dart:_internal                                             ListIterable.toList
package:stormberry/src/internals/view_query.dart 48:83     ViewQuery.apply
```

Lemme know incase more information is needed, I can update the question.

Any help would kind :)
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was from `postgres` package. Its now resolved and the PR has been merged:
https://github.com/schultek/stormberry/issues/50

Thanks to [Kilain](https://github.com/schultek)